# Can I track Activities , if i know the IP?

Tags: networking, ip, trace

Say if i have the IP of a user x.x.x.x , then using the IP can i track all the activities that the user is doing ? How can i do this ?

how can i check which web pages is the user opening or something similar

please guide

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot.  Traffic is point-to-point and knowing the address of a point is not enough to know the traffic going to/from that point.  It's like asking if you can read someones (snail) mail just because you know their house address.

In order to "snoop" that fully, you need to be in the middle where all traffic passes through your node (liking having the postman give you the mail and then you giving it to the owner of the house).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a machine, the traffic from the user is reaching it (e.g. you're connected to the same switch) then probably yes. The most trivial way is using network sniffer (Wireshark for windows, tcpdump for Linux).

However if the used surf SSL secured site (a.k.a https) than you will see only encrypted content

Comment: say i have someones ip , im not connected to the machine anyhow , it a remote machine , how can i even get the encrypted text if u say so ? HOW ?

Comment: You need to get the traffic. If you don't have physical access to the machine, than you need at least access to traffic the machine issues.

Comment: can i get the actual location of the IP , say i send a email from gmail and u get the IP , but that IP is of my ISP , and when i track that IP i get the location of the ISP not the location of the person who send it , can u help there ?

Comment: Try http://ping.eu/ns-whois/, http://ping.eu/nslookup/ or http://ping.eu/country-by-ip/

Answer (score 0):

Geolocation is not accurate because the primary source for IP address data is the Regional Internet Registries. They do not hold a database for information about individual IP addresses, but information about ranges of IP addresses that have been assigned to certain organizations. Such an organization has free reign over the IP addresses they get and they do not need to give location information to the RIRs. In other words, only your ISP knows your exact location. If you want to find the location of a user you will have to ask your ISP, and they will most probably deny your request.

You can't sniff packets sent from someone, unless you are part of the same subnet - you would have to be connected to the same switch and be on the same Virtual LAN as that user. Even if you somehow find the physical location of a user and connect to the same switch, the ISP has most likely sat up port security, which would deny access to your MAC address.

In conclusion, unless you are already connected to the same switch, you can't track that user's activities.

If you are connected to the same switch, you can install one of the popular packet sniffer utilities such as Wireshark and set it to promiscuous mode.